# Entire function bounded on real line and growth bounded by function of imaginary component

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $f\colon \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be an entire function taking reals to reals
and that is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose there exists a continuous function $g\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying
$$
|f(z)| \le g(\text{Im}(z)) \quad\quad (*)
$$
for every $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

One example is
$$
f(z) = e^{-z^2}\,.
$$
Of course, if $h\colon \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ is an entire function taking reals to reals and satisfying
$$
|h(z)|\le k(|z|)\quad\text{for some}~ k\colon\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} ~\text{continuous}\,,  
$$
and $f$ satisfies ($*$), then the composition $h\circ f$ satisfies ($*$).

Can we say anything else about real entire functions satisfying ($*$)? I'm interested in a Paley–Wiener type theorem for this class of functions but broadly interested in simple examples of this class of entire functions.

Comment: Using $x$ for a complex variable might confuse some people (like me) who are more used to the notation $z =x+iy$ with $x, y \in \Bbb R$.

Comment: no worries, changed to $z$

Comment: the only condition is that $f$ is bounded on lines parallel to the real axis (as automatically the bounds give you a continuous function $M(y)$ which is logarithmically convex ($\log M$ is convex) by the three-lines theorem; a nonconstant $f$ needs to have order at least $1$ (and non zero type) of course by Phragmen-Lindelof and if it it has order $1$ (and finite non zero type) then boundness only on $\mathbb R$ implies boundness on any parallel line and a representation in terms of measures on a real segment

Comment: Thanks Conrad. Yes log M convex, thanks. I guess Gaussian convolutions (on real line) will give many examples and may characterise a subclass.

Comment: It is well answered here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/190837/entire-function-bounded-at-every-line

Comment: One point conrad. An entire function bounded on horizontal lines need not be bounded on horizontal strips with non-empty interior. So it seems your proposed characterisation (or what I inderstand you are saying) is false